# What show was 007 attending at the pyramids?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, film-location, the-spy-who-loved-me

In the James Bond film *The Spy Who Loved Me*, what show was that that 007 attended by the pyramids? Was/is that a real production that tourists could/can attend? Or was that all for the sake of the story?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bond visited an enigmatic night-time laser show in the 1970s. This lightning show is currently still running. More info [here](https://www.memphistours.com/Egypt/Excursions/Cairo-Day-Tours/sound-light-show-at-giza-pyramids) and you can book through [this website](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g294201-d566605-Reviews-Pyramids_show-Cairo_Cairo_Governorate.html).

There may be additional info, but unfortunately I don't know arabian langauge, I was just a tourist there.

Comment: If that show is still running, can you include a source here instead of saying "check it on Google"?

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry [Here is the booking part](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g294201-d566605-Reviews-Pyramids_show-Cairo_Cairo_Governorate.html) and here is more info about it [Link](https://www.memphistours.com/Egypt/Excursions/Cairo-Day-Tours/sound-light-show-at-giza-pyramids) . There may be additional info, but unfortunately I don't know arabian langauge, I was just a tourist there.

Comment: Your answer could be enhanced if you moved the source and link from comment into the main answer.

Comment: Thanks! What would be interesting to see is if the audio narration is STILL the same as it was in that day. Doubtful, but interesting to know that's a real production!

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that the show in the film doesn't show real pyramids - they're models. So you're not actually seeing that real show on screen.

They couldn't practical way to light the pyramids for filming from the long distance needed, they could only light the sphinx.

See the ['Inside The Spy Who Loved Me'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kbTlgF-YcY&t=828s) making-of featurette from 27m40s on.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [original screenplay](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/the-spy-who-loved-me-1977.pdf) it would appear that this particular '*son et lumière*' (sound and light show) is an invention of the screenwriters since they indicate that it can be readily changed to suit the needs of the film.

> EXT. BACKSTAGE PYRAMIDS GIZAH NIGHT
>
> (NOTE: From this point , the *Son et Lumiere* performance provides only a background to the action of the picture and so **can be planned in detail at a later stage of the production; lighting, music and words being arranged to provide the most effective accompaniment to the drama)**.
>
> BOND is moving around in the shadows among the ruins, eerily lit by the reflected lights of the performance.

That being said, there are reports that [light shows were held at the pyramids as early as 1963](https://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1956&context=theses), so it's likely that the writers were intending to mimic these shows rather than it being their own idea.

> Outside of Europe the phenomenon spread as far afield as the Egyptian pyramids -  Glenn Loney's "*Electronic Drama*": THEATRE ARTS magazine. Vol 47 July 1963 p.27

[007 Magazine](http://007magazine.co.uk/factfiles/factfiles_trivia2.htm) credits repeat 007 actor Charles Gray with the narration of the show, again implying that it was custom-made for the film.

> The Spy Who Loved Me (1977) features a number of uncredited
> appearances, both on and off screen. **Narrator of part of the Egyptian
> ‘Son et Lumiere’ sequence at the Pyramids of Giza was English actor
> Charles Gray (1928-2000) who had played Henderson in You Only Live
> Twice (1967) [also directed by Lewis Gilbert], and Ernst Stavro
> Blofeld in Diamonds Are Forever (1971).** Charles Gray's association
> with the James Bond films actually goes back even further still. On
> November 28, 1963 Gray was selected to play Auric Goldfinger in Harold
> Sakata's screen test as Oddjob in Goldfinger (1964), although there is
> no evidence to suggest he was ever considered for the lead role of the
> eponymous villain himself.

Comment: Charles Gray, also of Rocky Horror fame.